# React.js URL changes but view does not change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React.js. I am using React.js 18.0.0. I am developing simple login application. Here I am facing problem in routing. When I click on forget password the URL alone changes but the view remains same. What have I done wrong.

My browser result:

[image]

My index.js:

[image]

My App.js:

[image]

Below is my Login.js where I have added Link:

[image]

Comment: I would assume (only) the "exact" on forget password might cause a problem, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react-router-dom version-6 then you can change your code as per the documentation
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md

**In index.js file**

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

**In App.js file**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App(){
return(
   <Routes>
      <Route  path="/" element={<Login/>}>
      <Route  path="/forgetPassword" element={<ForgetPassword/>}
   <Routes>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.js` file wrap the **App** component into **BrowserRouter** , React.StrictMode will appear first, I hope it will solve the issue. If you're using react-router-dom version 5, upgrade to version 6 and restart your project.

[image: Write your index.js file like this]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

change index.js to :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

change App.js to

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter ,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import ForgetPassword from '.........'
import Login from '.......' 


function App(){
return(
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Login/>} />
      <Route path="/forgetPassword" element={<ForgetPassword/>} />

   <Routes>


 </BrowserRouter>

 );

}

 export default App;



 if(document.getElementById('app')){

  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));

 }
```

Comment: Its getting blank page in browser result when I used like above.

Comment: did you import your login component in App.js? you need to import your login component and your ForgetPasswrod component there  `import Login from '.......'` and `import ForgetPassword from '.........'`

Comment: also remove exact from `<Route exact path="/forgetPassword" element={<ForgetPassword/} />` should be like this: `<Route path="/forgetPassword" element={<ForgetPassword/} />`

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js` file, just remove the `<React.StrictMode>` tag. In my case, it solved the problem. Sample snippet of index.js is given below:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
        </BrowserRouter> 
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be you are rendering in strict mode in your index.js file.

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(< App />);